# Will deleting my Steam account also revoke gifts I've sent?

Tags: steam

I have two Steam accounts one of which is a very old one that I don't use anymore and I'd like to delete. Over the years I've gifted some games using this account. If I delete it, do the gifts I've sent get revoked?

Steam FAQ page says:

> Account deletion is permanent. If you delete your Steam account: game
> licenses, community profile, gifts, inventory items, wallet funds, and
> other associated information will be deleted permanently and will not
> be recoverable.

But I'm not sure if that refers to gifts I've received (which will be deleted of course) or gifts I've sent too.

Comment: The only info I can find about gifts being revoked is due to payment dispute and fraud.  I can't see the system taking gifts back from users.  It be like if someone gave you a gift in real life, they disappear, and now some higher authority forces you to give that gift back because that person is missing... it just doesn't make sense for it to work that way.  This is likely talking about gifts you received instead.

Comment: I believe Steam allows you to merge an account into another, you may want to look into that possibility before deleting your account. If it's possible, you'd be able to have only one account and keep all your things!

Answer (score 3):

I would expect that when you delete your account, 'outgoing' gifts are not lost except if there's something else in the picture, like the payment for the gift was fraudulent.

From my understanding of how steam works, when you give a gift to someone, that someone gets the license, and is now unrelated to you. There might be a trace in the system that the payment came from you, but the license to the gifted, and not to the gifter with a clause of 'gifted can use it'.

Would be like if Grandma gave you an iPhone, but she died so you have to give it back. No, the iPhone is yours even if the one who spent the money to buy it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I would imagine it's like if you had a gift license in your inventory, but never sent it to anyone, that would disappear?

Comment: Yes that would very probably dissapear. Deleting your account will stop you from accessing stuff in your account so any item/game in your account will not be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The "gifts" they mention in their FAQ refer to the gifts you have in your inventory. When you buy a game as a gift, you're not forced to send it immediately upon purchase, you can keep it in your inventory. If you delete your account, you lose that unbound game license. It's a bit redundant with the mention to "inventory items"

Exemple:[image]